# Spring, Neo4j, searching with regular expressions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find results in neo4j's graph database in my Spring web app. Here is what I do:

```
@Query("START user=node:__types__(className='User') WHERE user.userName=~{0} OR user.firstName=~{0} OR user.lastName=~{0} RETURN user ORDER BY user.firstName, user.lastName")
Iterable<User> searchUsers(final String query);
```

I call it this way:

```
Iterable<User> users = usersService.searchUsers(String.format("(?i)%s.*", "All"));
```

And query is being executed well but it returns no results. It is actually a test and before users search I save several results to database:

```
    User userA = new User("Tinker", "password", "Percy", "Alleline", 25, "1234567890", "my_email@email.com", User.Gender.MALE, new Date());
    User userD = new User("Taylor", "password", "Bill", "Haydon", 24, "1234567890", "my_email@email.com", User.Gender.FEMALE, new Date());
    User userC = new User("Soldier", "password", "Roy", "Bland", 25, "1234567890", "my_email@email.com", User.Gender.MALE, new Date());
    User userB = new User("Spy", "password", "Toby", "Esterhase", 24, "1234567890", "my_email@email.com", User.Gender.FEMALE, new Date());

    userA.persist();
    userB.persist();
    userC.persist();
    userD.persist();
```

What is more, if I execute query directly on database, it finds results correctly.

```
START user=node:__types__(className = 'User') WHERE user.lastName=~ '(?i)to.*' OR user.firstName =~ '(?i)to.*' RETURN user ORDER BY user.firstName, user.lastName;
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of the solutions is to ensure that node **HAS(node.property)** the property that is the search criteria.

Working example below:

```
usersService.searchUsers(String.format("(?i).*%s.*", "All")); 

@Query("START user=node(*) WHERE HAS(user.firstName) AND (user.firstName=~{0} OR user.lastName=~{0}) RETURN user ORDER BY user.firstName, user.lastName")
Iterable<User> searchUsers(final String query);
```

If you come up with new better ones, provide them please.

Thank you.